# Uncaught Jquery Error- Help me

Tags: javascript, jquery, salesforce

Hi I am getting this error on my Visualforce Page.

> Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Here is my code

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" extensions="ActivityDetailExtension" standardStylesheets="false" sidebar="false">

   <apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.SLDS0105, '/assets/styles/salesforce-lightning-design-system-vf.css')}"/>

   <style>
   .table-border {margin-top:20px;}
   .table-border tr td {border: 1px solid #d8dde6;}
   .table-border tr th {border: 1px solid #d8dde6;}
   .sub-goal {margin-left:50px;}

   </style>

    <script>

            $(document).ready(function(){
               j$('#modal').removeClass('slds-fade-in-open');
               j$('#backdrop').removeClass('slds-backdrop--open');
            });

            //Modal Open
            j$('#toggleBtn').click(function(){
              j$('#backdrop').addClass('slds-backdrop--open');
              j$('#modal').addClass('slds-fade-in-open');
            });

            //Modal Close
            function closeModal(){
              j$('#modal').removeClass('slds-fade-in-open');
              j$('#backdrop').removeClass('slds-backdrop--open');
            }
 </script>

   <div class="slds">
  <apex:form >
<button class="slds-button slds-button--brand" id="toggleBtn" onclick="ShowModal">Create New Sub-Goal</button>
<div id="myModal">       
 <div role="dialog" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="header43" class="slds-modal slds-fade-in-open">
  <div class="slds-modal__container">
    <div class="slds-modal__header">
      <button class="slds-button slds-modal__close slds-button--icon-inverse" title="Close">
        <svg class="slds-button__icon slds-button__icon--large" aria-hidden="true">
         <!-- <use xlink:href="/assets/icons/utility-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#close"></use>-->
        </svg>
        <span class="slds-assistive-text">Close</span>
      </button>
      <h2 id="header43" class="slds-text-heading--medium">Modal Header</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="slds-modal__content slds-p-around--medium">
      <p>Sit nulla est ex deserunt exercitation anim occaecat. Nostrud ullamco deserunt aute id consequat veniam incididunt duis in sint irure nisi. Mollit officia cillum Lorem ullamco minim nostrud elit officia tempor esse quis. Cillum sunt ad dolore
        quis aute consequat ipsum magna exercitation reprehenderit magna. Tempor cupidatat consequat elit dolor adipisicing.</p>
      <p>Dolor eiusmod sunt ex incididunt cillum quis nostrud velit duis sit officia. Lorem aliqua enim laboris do dolor eiusmod officia. Mollit incididunt nisi consectetur esse laborum eiusmod pariatur proident. Eiusmod et adipisicing culpa deserunt nostrud
        ad veniam nulla aute est. Labore esse esse cupidatat amet velit id elit consequat minim ullamco mollit enim excepteur ea.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="slds-modal__footer">
      <button class="slds-button slds-button--neutral" onclick="closeModal()">Cancel</button>
      <button class="slds-button slds-button--brand">Save</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="slds-backdrop slds-backdrop--open"></div>
</div> 
</apex:form>       
   </div>
</apex:page>
```

I am using the toggle functionality of Lightning Design system which will toggle my div. So if div is present then it will show the popup on button click otherwise when my page is opened the toggle or modal will not show.This page is a visualforce page
I am using Lightning Design system of Salsesforce please help me into this.

Comment: Is jQuery loaded? `$` being undefined would signify it wasn't. Also why are you doing `j$`?

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek : Jquery is not lodded. And i am using j$ for no conflict.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You initialise your page with $ but you have to do it with j$. Because of your using of no conflict replacement.

==> $(document).ready(function(){
               j$('#modal').removeClass('slds-fade-in-open');
               j$('#backdrop').removeClass('slds-backdrop--open');
            });

           ...